# Javascript function to prevent link open on based condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to put one condition so that user can open the link only when the condition is fulfill. Here what I did:

```
function check(data) {
        if (data < 20){
            alert("Please buy minimum $20");
    }
```

And html:

```
<a href= "go" onclick= "check(<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>) return ;">Go checkout?</a>
```

But problem is when user click on OK button from alert box they redirect to 'go' page. How do I prevent so that they can open link if condition is fulfill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your onclick function returns false then the page wont redirect

```
function check(data) {
        if (data < 20){
            alert("Please buy minimum $20");
            return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

and your html

```
<a href= "go" onclick= "return check(<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>) ;">Go checkout?</a>
```

Comment: +1. Was typing exactly the same answer. As an additional remark, it would be better not to use inline javascript (=`onclick` attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Sample way is to use **return false;** if the user not empty data.